# JQuery slide horizontal onclick

Tags: jquery

Can you please tell me how to use slide div in horizontal when onclick Prev/Next images using ajax load in jQuery.

My logic looks like this :

```
jQuery("#appt_1").click(function() {
    jQuery("#appt_1").load("/test/get_later_slots")
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this to slide a div right and "delete it" from a set

```
$('#'+val).hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500, function() {
            $('#'+val).remove();
        });
```

You may be able to modify it to work for your situation.

Comment: thanks, yes i removed $('#'+val).remove(); and changed .hide to .show and it works .

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer to use a plugin, i suggest to use this one:

- [**Jcarousel**](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html)

Comment: yeah, but i will load data only when click on next/prev buttons. i found with jcarousel will load data at once . right ?

Comment: he have a example getting values from a ajax source

Answer (score 0):

you can use animate option in jquery and slide ur div to left or right!

ex.

```
$("#id1").click(function() {
    $("#id2").animate ({
right:'120px', opacity:'1'},500);

});
```

initially i ll keep the opacity:0 for #id2 so as to keep it hidden and on click will change the opacity to 1 as simple as that!!